# Python BeautifulSoup: Insert attribute to tags

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to insert a new attribute to all the nested tables in a html doc. I'm trying with the code below, but it's not inserting the attribute to all the table tags. I would really appreciate any help.

Input html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<table>
<tr>t<td><table></table></td></tr>
<tr>t<td><table></table></td></tr>
<tr>t<td><table></table></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib2

html = urllib2.urlopen("file://xxxxx.html").read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for tag in soup.find_all(True):
        if (tag.name == "table"):
                tag['attr'] = 'new'
                print(tag)
        else:
                print(tag.contents)
```

Output html code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<div>
<table attr="new">
<tr>t<td><table attr="new"></table></td></tr>
<tr>t<td><table attr="new"></table></td></tr>
<tr>t<td><table attr="newe"></table></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is the problem with reference to the actual html?

Comment: @VikasNehaOjha The problem is the code is not inserting the attribute to all 'table' tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `tag['attr'] = 'new'` seems to work correctly.  The problem is that `print(tag.contents)` will print parts of the document recursively before the descendants have been modified.

The simple fix is to make one pass to modify the document first, then make just one `print(soup)` call at the end.

Comment: how to add readyonly attribute?